# List of Variable Instances

Tags: python, list, instance

Bellow is my current code, I am pretty new to Python. I am trying to create a list of Photo instances, where each Photo instance uses the data from each tuple in the tups_list. and save that list in a variable photo_insts. Currently I am not receiving an error, literally, nothing is happening in terminal when I try to run the file.

```
photo_insts = []
tups_list = [("Portrait 2","Gordon Parks",["chicago", "society"]),("Children in School","Dorothea Lange",["children","school","1930s"]),("Airplanes","Margaret Bourke-White",["war","sky","landscape"])]
class Photo2(object):
    def __init__(self, title_str, photo_by,tags_list):
        self.title = title_str
        self.artist = photo_by
        self.tags = tags_list
        for i in tups_list:
            photo_tuple = (i[0],i[1],i[2])
            photo_insts.append(photo_tuple)
            print i
```

---

Below are tests to run to check for diffrent values:

```
class Phototest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_photo_insts1(self):
        self.assertEqual(type(photo_insts),type([]))
    def test_photo_insts2(self):
        self.assertEqual(type(photo_insts[0]),type(Photo("Photo2","Photo Student",["multiple","tags"])))
    def test_photo_insts3(self):
        self.assertEqual([x.title for x in photo_insts],["Portrait 2", "Children in School", "Airplanes"])
    def test_photo_insts4(self):
        self.assertEqual([x.artist for x in photo_insts],["Gordon Parks","Dorothea Lange","Margaret Bourke-White"])
    def test_photo_insts5(self):
        self.assertEqual([x.tags for x in photo_insts],[["chicago","society"],["children", "school","1930s"],["war","sky","landscape"]])
```

Comment: If what you posted is the entirety of your code - then only the first two lines have any effect; the definition of ``class Photo2`` is pointless, because you never create any instances of that class.  Those last 4 lines should probably be outside of the class, and should create a ``Photo2()`` instead of a tuple.

Comment: @ jasonharper I am still a little confused, I thought that I created instances for class Photo2 with my def __init__(self, title_str, photo_by,tags_list): and the listed attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a typo:

`photo_tuple = (i[0],i[1],i[2])`

=>

`photo_tuple = Photo2 (i[0],i[1],i[2])`

Function `__init__` is called on creation of an instance `Photo2`. 
If you call `Photo2 ()` within the function `__init__` then you get a recursion !

=> The code should look like :

```
class Photo2(object):
    def __init__(self, title_str, photo_by, tags_list):
        self.title  = title_str
        self.artist = photo_by
        self.tags   = tags_list
# end class
tups_list = [
     ("Portrait 2","Gordon Parks",["chicago", "society"])
    ,("Children in School","Dorothea Lange",["children","school","1930s"])
    ,("Airplanes","Margaret Bourke-White",["war","sky","landscape"])
    ]
photo_insts = []
for i in tups_list :
    photo_tuple = Photo2 (i[0],i[1],i[2])
    photo_insts.append(photo_tuple)
    print i[0]
for p in photo_insts :
    print repr (p)
```

Output in console :

```
Portrait 2
Children in School
Airplanes
<__main__.Photo2 object at 0xb7082cac>
<__main__.Photo2 object at 0xb7082ccc>
<__main__.Photo2 object at 0xb7082cec>
```

Comment: @ Zohl Martin Great thanks! It seems to be mostly working now.....but I am getting one traceback  when comaparing it to class Phototest(unittest.TestCase): ........any ideas???    self.assertEqual(type(photo_insts[0]),type(Photo("Photo2","Photo Student",["multiple","tags"])))
AssertionError: <class '__main__.Photo2'> != <class '__main__.Photo'>

Comment: The name of class is Photo2 and not Photo.  The unittest raises traceback because it does not know a variable "Photo".   I think it would be better to use function "isinstance" to check the type of the class - in your case: isinstance (photo_insts[0], Photo2)